# XML CDATA section special character encoding Error when trying to open in browser

Tags: python, xml, cdata

I have several XML files on our Amazon S3 server with our company's ads we want to display on various sites. Some of them require all the info with CDATA tags. But when I try to open the file with my browser it always gives me encoding Errors because of the special characters in the text. The text for each file is in another language (French, Spanish, etc.).

But isn't the CDATA section meant to ignore all special characters? I'm pretty new to Python, XML, etc, but I couldn't find an answer on Google (maybe I'm phrasing the problem in a wrong way, idk).

As soon as I encode the special characters (e.g. &) and remove the CDATA tags I can view the file with my browser without problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<source xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

<job>
<id><![CDATA[removed]]></id>
<url><![CDATA[removed]]></url>
<title><![CDATA[removed]]></title>
<description><![CDATA[removed]]></description>
<date><![CDATA[removed]]></date>
<country><![CDATA[removed]]></country>
<city><![CDATA[removed]]></city>
<company><![CDATA[removed]]></company>
</job>

</source>
```

I expected to be able to put any special characters into CDATA without any problems but I'm not able to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using CDATA means you don't need to escape the XML-special characters like "<" and "&" as `&lt;` and `&amp;`. But it doesn't affect the handling of non-ASCII characters such as French accented letters. These need to be encoded (not escaped) using the character encoding declared in the XML declaration, just as if they were not in CDATA. (It's very anglo-centric to regard these characters as being in any way "special").

Comment: Thanks for your answer Michael! Straight forward and well explained. I still have a lot to learn, but I'll get there :). Have a nice week!

Comment: One thing I don't understand is that I have one xml file with the apparently exact same format where I can put in all different kind of French accented letters without the need to encode them and the file can be displayed normally without the usual errors. I've used the exact same text in two different files and the one I've just mentioned displayed it perfectly fine while the other one gave an encoding error. Do you know if there is an explanation for it? The declaration and format should have been exactly the same.

Comment: No, I can't explain that. There must be some other difference between the fies that you haven't noticed and therefore haven't told us about.